# Writing to file results in empty file

Tags: c++, file-io

I wrote a small program that opens a file, builds a vector from every line in the file and then have the user able to add/remove from the file. The program first removes from the vector, then rebuilds the file based on the vector. Here's the code that rebuilds the file (fileName is a member variable with the full name of the text file, ex. "test.txt":

```
bool rebuildFile() {
    if (remove(fileName.c_str()) == 0) {    // remove the old file
        ofstream newFile(fileName);         // create new file with same name
        newFile.open(fileName, ios::app);   // open to append to end of file
        if (newFile.is_open()) {            
            newFile << fileHeader << endl;  // add the first header line
            for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {  // loop through vector, adding strings to file
                newFile << myVector[i] << endl;   // I used "\n" instead of endl, but both give same results
            }
            newFile.close();
            return true;     // success
        }
    }
    return false;            // failure
}
```

After this function exits, the file is completely empty. So it clearly creates a new file, but then the writing part is an issue, and I can't figure out why. I read other posts where some had issues where they had the file open in Notepad/Notepad++, but I've always made sure to close that specific file before running the program. I'm not sure if the ios::app flag is causing an issue with the loop, but the documentation seems clear that it just points to the end of the file every time you output to it, so I don't think the issue is there. Any thoughts?

EDIT:

Apparently you can't append to an empty file... This new code works, but I'm not sure if there's a "cleaner" way to add to a file in two different ways without opening and closing it twice using different flags.

new code:

```
bool rebuildFile() {
    if (remove(fileName.c_str()) == 0) {
        std::ofstream newFile(fileName);
        newFile.open(fileName);
        if (newFile.is_open()) {
            newFile << fileHeader << endl;
            newFile.close();
        }
        newFile.open(fileName, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
        if (newFile.is_open()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {
                newFile << myVector[i] << endl;
            }
            newFile.close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So you remove the old file, create a new file and then append to that file which contains nothing? O.o I don't get it.

Comment: I didn't think that would be an issue... I thought I could still append to the file, just that the end would also be the beginning of the file.

Comment: Thanks deW1, that was the issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to call `open` on an already open file stream puts the stream in a failed state.

Just change

```
ofstream newFile(fileName);         // create new file with same name
    newFile.open(fileName, ios::app);
```

to

```
ofstream newFile(fileName, ios::app);
```

---

[ofstream.members]

> `void open(const char* s, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);`
>
> Eﬀects: Calls `rdbuf()->open(s, mode | ios_base::out)`. If that
>   function does **not return a null pointer** calls `clear()`, **otherwise calls
>   `setstate(failbit)`** (which may throw `ios_base::failure` (27.5.5.4)).

[ﬁlebuf.members]

> `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>* open(const char* s, ios_base::openmode mode);`
>
> Eﬀects: If `is_open() != false`, **returns a null pointer**. [...]
>
> `bool is_open() const;`
>
> Returns: **true if a previous call to `open` succeeded** (returned a
>   non-null value) and there has been **no intervening call to close**.

Answer (score 0):

```
ofstream newFile(fileName);
```

doesn't just create the file, it opens it too. And that means you can't open it again.

I don't see a reason to remove the file, re-create it - truncating if it exists - and open it, write a little, close the file, open it *again* but for appending, and then write to it some more.

Plus, if you run out of luck, there's an opportunity for a different process to modify (or delete) the file between the first `close` and the second `open`, which is in general not a good thing.

This snippet should work:

```
bool rebuildFile()
{
   std::ofstream newFile(fileName);
   if (newFile)
   {
      newFile << fileHeader << endl;
      for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {
         newFile << myVector[i] << endl;
      }
   }
   return newFile;
}
```

(Files are closed automatically, if needed, by `ofstream`'s destructor.)